# my assembly plugin in maven does not archive all the artifacts in my final jar, well sometimes it does and sometimes it does'nt , i am perplexed

Tags: maven-assembly-plugin

m in a bit of a fix..... needless mention m very new to maven

googled out stuff and created a multi module project .....i use an assembly.xml tagged to my master POM to archive all the modules artifact   *.jar into a final si-installer.jar .

### here is wat my master pom is like

```
 <modules>
    <module>si_config_support/src/main/java/com/tcs/bancs/si</module>
    <module>SI_CORE/src/main/xsd</module>
    <module>SI_CORE/src/main/java/com/tcs/bancs/si/core</module>
    <module>SI_CORE/src/main/java/com/tcs/bancs/si/impl/adapter/jmsadapter</module>
    <module>SI_CORE/src/main/java/com/tcs/bancs/si/impl/actions</module>
    <module>SI_CORE/src/main/java/com/tcs/bancs/si/core/process/message</module>
    <module>SI_CORE/src/main/java/com/tcs/bancs/si/main</module>
</modules>

<build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-7</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>  

    <plugins>
        <plugin>

<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>  
<artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
<version>1.0-beta-3</version>  
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>upload-javadoc</id>
      <phase>deploy</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>upload</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <serverId>InBlrBnc107</serverId>
        <fromDir>/home0/u485309/User/Maven_SonarTest/target</fromDir>
        <includes>*.jar</includes>
        <excludes>pom.xml</excludes>
        <url>http://172.19.97.248:8081/artifactory/simple</url>
        <toDir>SIDeployment/Service-Integrator/si-main</toDir>
      </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    </plugin>


        <!--plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>deploy</phase>
        <configuration>
          <target>
            <scp file="/home0/u485309/User/Maven_SonarTest/target/si-installer-9.0.jar" todir="sidevperf:password@172.19.98.18:/home/sidevperf/USERS" trust="true"/>
          </target>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
     <dependencies>
          <dependency>  
            <groupId>ant-jsch</groupId>  
            <artifactId>ant-jsch</artifactId>  
            <version>1.8.1</version>  
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>          
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>           
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>          
            <version>0.1.42</version>       
       </dependency>  
     </dependencies> 
  </plugin-->

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <createChecksum>true</createChecksum>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <finalName>si-installer-9.0</finalName>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>si-assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <attach>false</attach>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.tcs.mswitch.installer.Install</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/installer/thirdparty-lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        <includeScope>provided</includeScope>
                        <outputAbsoluteArtifactFilename>true</outputAbsoluteArtifactFilename>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>    
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

### and my si assembly is like this:

```
<assembly>
<id>Service-Integrator</id>
<formats>
    <format>jar</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>/home0/u485309/User/Maven_SonarTest/si_config_support/src/main/java/com/tcs/bancs/si/target</directory>
        <outputDirectory>SI_COMPONENTS/lib</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>si-config-support-9.0.jar</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>/home0/u485309/User/Maven_SonarTest/SI_CORE/src/main/xsd/target</directory>
        <outputDirectory>SI_COMPONENTS/lib</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>si-config-9.0.jar</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>/home0/u485309/User/Maven_SonarTest/SI_CORE/src/main/java/com/tcs/bancs/si/core/target</directory>
        <outputDirectory>SI_COMPONENTS/lib</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>si-core-9.0.jar</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>

    <fileSet>
        <directory>/home0/u485309/User/Maven_SonarTest/SI_CORE/src/main/java/com/tcs/bancs/si/impl/adapter/jmsadapter/target</directory>
        <outputDirectory>SI_COMPONENTS/lib</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>si-jms-adapter-9.0.jar</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>/home0/u485309/User/Maven_SonarTest/SI_CORE/src/main/java/com/tcs/bancs/si/impl/actions/target</directory>
        <outputDirectory>SI_COMPONENTS/lib</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>si-processing-actions-9.0.jar</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>/home0/u485309/User/Maven_SonarTest/SI_CORE/src/main/java/com/tcs/bancs/si/core/process/message/target</directory>
        <outputDirectory>SI_COMPONENTS/lib</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>si-message-processor-9.0.jar</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>/home0/u485309/User/Maven_SonarTest/SI_CORE/src/main/java/com/tcs/bancs/si/main/target</directory>
        <outputDirectory>SI_COMPONENTS/lib</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>si-main-9.0.jar</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>/home0/u485309/User/Maven_SonarTest/installer/groovy-dependencies</directory>
        <outputDirectory/>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*</include>
        </includes>
        <!--excludes>
            <exclude>META-INF/**/*</exclude>
        </excludes-->
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>/home0/u485309/User/Maven_SonarTest/installer/thirdparty-lib</directory>
        <outputDirectory>SI_COMPONENTS/thirdparty-lib</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>*.jar</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>bancsjmx-2.0.jar</exclude>
            <exclude>xsd.jar</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>/home0/u485309/User/Maven_SonarTest/installer/thirdparty-lib</directory>
        <outputDirectory>SI_COMPONENTS/lib</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>bancsjmx-2.0.jar</include>
            <!--include>xsd.jar</include-->
        </includes>
    </fileSet>

    <fileSet>
        <directory>/home0/u485309/User/Maven_SonarTest/DeliveryComponents</directory>
        <outputDirectory>SI_COMPONENTS</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

I have 2 problems-:

1) all my phases run for each module so my si-installer.jar which would be my final jar gets created for all the module and also the ant task is run for all the modules..also the uploading to artifactory using wagon happens for all the phases ? how can i stop phases like package and deploy to run only after compilation for all the sub modules have been done?

2) my final artifact jar si-installer.jar sometimes has all my sub modules jar while at other times only a single jar(bancsjmx.jar mentioned last in the fileset of assembly.xml) comes in the final artifact si-installer.jar which is bancsjmx.jar in the assembly.xml  , i am perplexed? also this behaviour is sporadic...sometimes i get all my jars in the final jar ....sometimes as i said only one..seems like maven doing some multithreaded stuff....wen slow things go fine!!! please help

have somebody faced such issues before?